# Linking a String to a Function

Tags: java, android, hashmap, runnable, enumeration

Is there a way in Java (Android) to link a string and a function? My aim is to run a certain function depending on what string is received from a seperate method.

ie if myString == "building" then execute buildingmethod();

I was thinking about using a HashMap like so:

```
HashMap<String,Runnable> hashDBTableUpdateRef = new HashMap<>();
hashDBTableUpdateRef.put("house",this.housemethod());
hashDBTableUpdateRef.put("shed",this.shedmethod());
hashDBTableUpdateRef.put("barn",this.barnmethod());
```

then

```
String myString = getCalculatedString();
for (String s : hashDBTableUpdateRef) {
    hashDBTableUpdateRed.get(s).run();
}
```

I can't really make a generic method with a parameter, such as `function anyBuilding(String buildingType)` due to following actions and custom enumerations. Any thoughts? Is `runnable` the way forward?

eg:

```
function housemethod() {
    myHouseObject.runSomething();
}
function shedmethod() {
    myShedObject.runSomething();
}
function barnmethod() {
    myBarnObject.runSomething();
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: I feel design smell here

Comment: You could very well be right

Comment: Please provide more context, e.g. where does that string come from?

Comment: You have not given us anything to work with for determining what approach might be most suitable.  What you propose is not inherently bad, but it is very vanilla.  Your specific problem might afford a better specific solution.

Comment: Btw, `hashDBTableUpdateRed.get(s).run();` looks really odd in that loop (which shouldn't compile anyways). I guess you mean `hashDBTableUpdateRed.get(myString).run();` without the loop and some checks as well - Note that this is a side note and is not meant to solve your potential design problem.

Comment: Reflection, Reflection, and Reflection ?!

Comment: Yes, I'm after a tidier approach, more generic, than a huge list of if-then-else statements. Map<String,Method> ?

Comment: A key question here is whether the lists of strings you want to map and methods you want to invoke must be modifiable at run time.

Comment: @Jammo, any *means* to avoid reflection is also a good *reason* to avoid reflection.  Use reflection only if you absolutely must.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could for example define enum which implements `Command` interface

```
interface Command {
        void execute();
    }

    enum MyEnum implements Command {
        A() {
            public void execute() {
                System.out.println("A");
            }
        },
        B {
            public void execute() {
                System.out.println("B");
            }
        };
    }
```

now all what you need is convert your string to enum `MyEnum.valueOf("someString");` and you returned object you can call `execute` method.

But still main question remain, why you want to do this and what you want to achieve? because it might be better way.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks, worked a treat.
`mapDbUpdater = new HashMap<String, Command>();
mapDbUpdater.put("shed", new Command() {
            @Override
            public void doSomething() {
                shed.refreshDbContents();
            }
        });`

Comment: Then I use `try { Command updaterCommand = mapDbUpdater.get(tableNameToUpdate);
            updaterCommand.doSomething();`

Comment: @Jammo - Dynamically overriding the method is completely unnecessary. Use `MyEnum.valueOf("shed").execute()`.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon, are you saying `mapDbUpdater.valueOf("shed").doSomething();` ?

Comment: Ah yes. Good spot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your are quite near to get what you want, but you should replace the generic `Runnable` by a specific interface:

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    public <return-type> doSomething(<parameters>) throws <exceptions>;
}
```

This is a *semantic* way to improve your initial design, because you can *name* your methods, add parameters and exceptions, add more methods, etc.

The rest of your design (a specific implementation for each needed behaviour, and storing them all in a Map) is OK.

Comment: Maybe.  Probably.  On the other hand, it could also be that `Runnable` in fact captures as specific a representation of the target tasks as there is, in which case creating a different type to represent the same thing would be more harmful than helpful.

Comment: @John Bollinger Of corse, that's up to the developper's decission. I just meant that he/she must not feel limited by `Runnable`.